# MYSQL database connection inside endless loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that runs forever while (1) in that script i do some db calls. I open and close the db connection for every query..

Is this good practice, or should the open connection be outside the loop without ever closing. The script if errors respawns via shell script..

Comment: Do you have full control over the PHP server? if you don't then you might run into problems with the script running out of execution time if whoever manages the PHP server has set a maximum execution time for all PHP scripts on that server

Comment: yeah i do .. haven;t had an execution time outs yet.. the loop checks and api .. nothing too complicated

Comment: What type of queries are being run (eg SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc)? Do they have to be run in "real-time" or could they be run in bulk say once an hour?

Comment: Update queries.. need to run in real time.. simple status updates that on the next iteration goes though a switch statement for next task

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You haven't given much explanation about your scenario, and there could be reasons to handle connections in different ways depending on what you're doing.

If your script sleeps for some time in between queries, I would close the database connection. Leaving an idle database connection open unnecessarily can be wasteful, because an open connection uses a little bit of RAM on the database server even when you aren't running a query.

But if your script runs queries rapidly, without sleeping in the loop, then it would be wasteful to disconnect only to reconnect again immediately. There is a little bit of delay and CPU cost caused by connecting to the db server.

You should also handle cases where the database connection is terminated in between queries. A good way to handle this is to check for errors when you query, and either retry the connection and the query, or else in your case just exit the PHP script, since it will be respawned anyway.

In short, there are exceptions to every rule, and you haven't given enough information in your question to make a clear recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. It does at minimum one select query every iteration.. With a maximum of 4 - 5 in one iteration.. ie if it's doing more than one query in one iteration the next one will be back to 1 select..

The multiple query exe happen about 4 or 5 times a day and it's looping with a sleep of 10 seconds